# Share Brackets config with teammembers

Tags: adobe-brackets

I've configured my Brackets-installation with different extensions and it would be nice if I could provide a ready-to-go bundle of brackets with all extensions to all team-members, so that they don't have to install and configure all plugins manually.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You could try the [Extension Bulk Installer](https://github.com/milosh86/Brackets-ExtensionsBulkInstall).
For sharing the settings, put the settings into a `.brackets.json` file in your project root and include it in your version control.